# Merge rows depending on 2 column values

Tags: r, dplyr

```
region.  age.   pop 
SSC21184    0   209
SSC21184    1   195
SSC21184    2   242
SSC21184    3   248
SSC21185    0   231
SSC21185    1   287
SSC21185    2   268
SSC21185    3   257
```

I'm looking to:

- group age groups (column 2) for ages <2 and >=2,
- find the population for these age groups, for each region

so it should look something like this:

```
region.  age_group.   pop 
SSC21184    <2       404
SSC21184    >=2      490
SSC21185    <2       518
SSC21185    >=2      524
```

I've attempted using `tapply(df$pop, df$agegroup, FUN = mean) %>% as.data.frame()`, however I continue to get the error: arguments must have same length

Edit: If possible, how would I be able to plot the population per age group per region? As for example, a stacked bar graph?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have only two age groups to change we can use `ifelse` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(region, age = ifelse(age >=2, '>=2', '<2')) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(pop))


#   region   age     sum
#  <chr>    <fct> <int>
#1 SSC21184 < 2     404
#2 SSC21184 >=2     490
#3 SSC21185 < 2     518
#4 SSC21185 >=2     525
```

A more general solution would be with `cut` if you have large number of age groups.

```
df %>%
  group_by(region, age = cut(age, breaks = c(-Inf, 1, Inf), 
                   labels = c('< 2', '>=2'))) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(pop))
```

---

We can use the same logic in `tapply` as well.

```
with(df, tapply(pop, list(region, ifelse(age >=2, '>=2', '<2')), sum))

#         <2 >=2
#SSC21184 404 490
#SSC21185 518 525
```

Comment: You are a superstar

Comment: would you know how I would plot each region in a barplot in ggplot?

Comment: @yupper Please don't extend/edit your question after it has been answered. Each post should be focussed on one single problem. If you have additional question ask that as a new question.